# custom uitableviewcell for login input - username & password

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uitableview

I want to create a simple table view with one section and two rows - one for username and another for password, similar to *Skype login* (screenshot here: http://i33.photobucket.com/albums/d74/chaks_2k/IMG_0143.png)

Just two rows, one for username and another for password.

Is there any out of the box cell style i can use for this or should I create a custom table view cell? It really looks like this is a common control that anybody wants in their application if they want to input username and password.

Thanks,
Chaks

Answer (score 0):

Yes ofcourse you do need to use Custom cells to make such kind of layout.

Otherwise one easy way :

Set the image for email & password just like cell & place two textfields over there.That would also look like tableView cells .

In addition to this ,If you follow this you can customize your view very easily with less coding & making a rich layout.